# How to connect dialogflow and actions.xml?

Tags: android, actions-on-google, app-actions

Google DialogFlow will use cloud compute to handle user request, so that I can process huge text input and throw to a certain INTENT(Android INTENT)

What can I response to let google assistant uses slice fulfillment defined in actions.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this stage (Sept 2019), the implementation of an Assistant [Custom Conversation](https://developers.google.com/actions/conversational/overview) (for which [DialogFlow](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/) is one option for fulfilment) is completely separate to [App Actions](https://developers.google.com/actions/appactions/overview) (which uses `actions.xml` inside your Android app code).

[Slices](https://developers.google.com/actions/appactions/slices) are part of the App Actions implementation and are therefore not related to Assistant Custom Conversations.